# Solving Challenge -- Accessing Object Properties in a Function

Tags: javascript, object

Challenge:

1. create an object named team with two properties, partner1 and partner2
2. write a function sayTeamNames that accepts a single parameter teamObj
3. have that sayTeamNames log both partner names separated by ' and '
4. call sayTeamNames with your team object

```js
const team = {
  partner1: 'Bob,
  partner2: 'Julie'
}

function sayTeamNames(teamObj) {
  for (var key in teamObj) {
    console.log(teamObj[key] + ' and ' + teamObj[key])
  }
}

sayTeamNames(team)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems I see:

1. lose the `,` after the `Julie`
2. lose the `'` for `Bob`

```js
const team = {
  partner1: 'Bob',
  partner2: 'Julie',
}

function sayTeamNames(teamObj) {
  for (var key in teamObj) {
    console.log(teamObj[key] + ' and ' + teamObj[key])
  }
}

sayTeamNames(team)
```

Note that based on the code, it will ouput `Bob and Bob Julie and Julie` if you want display something like `Bob and Julie`, use

```js
const team = {
  partner1: 'Bob',
  partner2: 'Julie',
}

function sayTeamNames(teamObj) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(teamObj).length; i += 2) {
    console.log(Object.values(teamObj)[i] + ' and ' + Object.values(teamObj)[i + 1])
  }
}

sayTeamNames(team)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
  const team = {
          partner1: 'Bob',
          partner2: 'Julie'
        }
    
        function sayTeamNames(teamObj) {
          console.log(Object.values(teamObj).join(' and '))
        }
    
        sayTeamNames(team)
```